# Best Practices for Vaulting EAV

Tags: entity-attribute-value, data-vault

One of the source systems I am trying to vault holds a set of two tables that operate as entity attribute value tables.  I am wondering what are the best methods people have used to move these tables into a Data Vault 2.0 model.

Answer (score 0):

Working on a RDBMS that stores data in an EAV model, we have simply made these tables into multi-active satellites with the entity as the business concept which we stored in a HUB.